# how to send mail in google cloud hosting

Tags: email, laravel-5, google-cloud-platform, mailgun

I am using Google cloud hosting with Laravel application.
I have integrate mailgun for mail and proper working no any error .
My issue is not receive mail when we have check server mail log

> May 26 11:59:55 instance-1 sendmail[22013]: v4OGpxfB003667: to=, delay=1+19:07:56, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=4088715, relay=alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection timed out with alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.

I am using `mailgun` not `gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com`.

how to send mail ??

Comment: I changed MX record and i am try this https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/using-mailgun but not success

Comment: Have you configured your Laravel application to use the mail gun email settings?